# Why is this javascript getting called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have a button where I've hooked the onclick to a call to retrieve the users location and then use the location to make another call to retrieve a list of nearby locations. For some reason the geolocation success method is being called twice on the second click of the button.

So I load the page, click the button, allow permission to use my location, and it will make one ajax request to get the nearby locations. This works fine.

I click the button again, allow permission to use my location (again), it will make one ajax request to get the locations, wait ~2 seconds, and then make another request using the same coordinates without me allowing permission. So the success method has to be getting called twice, but I'm not sure why.

```
$("#FindLocation").click(function () {
  myScript.findNearbyLocations(displayData, displayError);
});
```

This click function is not being called twice and I've commented out all the code in displayData and displayError.

```
findNearbyLocations: function (onSuccess, onFailure) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      alert('This is getting called twice except on the initial call.');
      myScript.findStores(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, onSuccess, onFailure);
    }, function () {
      onFailure(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Edit: I don't think the markup is the problem. I'm only using basic webpages for testing. There is no styling or other elements at the moment.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>      
    <MyControls:Search ID="Search" runat="server" />
  </div>
</form>
```

and the user control (along with all the necessary javascript includes)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FindLocation").click(function () {
      myScript.findNearbyLocations(displayData, displayError);
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="button" id="FindLocation" value="Find Location" />
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't onFailure be false on your last line there?

Comment: @DOK, that would depend on what his `onFailure` method does with the parameter passed to it.

Comment: @DOK, no, that function just takes in whether or not the browser supports the navigator.geolocation funcationality. Since we made it into the if statement, I know it is supported, but the user may have denied access to use their location.

Comment: Could you possibly inadvertently have two elements on the page with `id='FindLocation'`? It's not supposed to be allowed to have a duplicate ID, but JQuery copes with it and will run the event for each of them.

Comment: @Spudley, afraid not. It's an empty webpage with the basic html/head/body tags, and a user control. No other elements. The user control just contains the one button and a div to dump the results in.

Comment: what is your server and authentication structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a bug in the `getCurrentPosition` of whatever client you are using.
In that case you could simply set a flag when the success method is called and not allow the `findStores`  function to be called a 2nd time.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have found this happening, it's because I accidentally bound the event to the control twice.

If the code

```
$("#FindLocation").click(function () {
  myScript.findNearbyLocations(displayData, displayError);
});
```

happens to be run twice, you will have two identical click events bound, and the action will happen twice.

Comment: I have that code in the document.ready function. I don't believe it is being bound twice. I put an alert before the findNearbyLocations call and it only gets called once each time for the first and subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, it seems to be a browser bug (tested in Firefox and Safari). I simply verified whether I already had retrieved the same data within a recent timeframe, similar to what is answered here: [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition sometimes works sometimes doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt)

More questions in Google but no definitive answer: http://www.google.nl/search?q=geolocation.getCurrentPosition+called+twice&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: +1 for confirming it is a bug. Guess I'll go with wosis' answer and just pass in a flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this IS happening, and it IS happening with predictable frequency; what I've found in an app I'm working on right now is that when an error is raised and not caught, somewhere in some anonymous function that *appears* to terminate the current Javascript sessions, that's when it begins happening. It's frustrating and annoying; I know *why* it's happening, but I don't know *where* it's happening... yet.

But it *is*, so just a quick comment that all the "that can't happen" answers aren't terribly accurate or helpful.

Anyway, that's my answer; you may have some inner-function tossing an error that JQuery is quietly eating or something.

$.02