# function fail never called if user declines to share geolocation in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, callback, geolocation

So I have this javascript code. In safari and chrome, if user declines to share location, it goes to fail function as it should; however, in Firefox, it does not.

Any helps appreciated.

```
function initGeolocation()
{
    if( navigator.geolocation )
    {          
          // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
    }
    else
    {
          alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
    }
}

 var map;
 function success(position)
 {

     var longIDText = document.getElementById('longID');
     var latIDText = document.getElementById('latID');
     longIDText.value = position.coords.longitude;
     latIDText.value = position.coords.latitude;
     document.getElementById('coordSubmitID').click();
  }

  function fail(error)
  {
          alert("FAAAAAAAAAAIIIIIIIIIL")
          var zip_code ;
          while (true){
              // Could not obtain location

              zip_code = prompt("Please enter your current address or zip code","");


              if ( zip_code == "" ) {
                  alert(zip_code +" is not a valid address. Please try again.");
              } 
              else{
                break;
              }
          }
          var zipIDText = document.getElementById('zipID');
          zipIDText.value = zip_code;
          document.getElementById('coordSubmitID').click();
  }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Firefox it [seems that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591745) `PERMISSION_DENIED` is raised **only** if "Never share" is selected; if the dialog is dismissed or "Not now" is selected, effectively nothing happens - even on [mozillas geolocation demo](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/#geo-demo) if you dismiss the permissions UI nothing happens.

This means that `getCurrentPosition` can return either because the user closed the confirmation UI, or because it successfully started it asynchronous request - there doesn't appear to be a way to discriminate between the two.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533

Comment: Indeed.  "Not now" is no different from the user looking at the notification and thinking about it.  In particular, after selecting "Not Now" the user can go back to the dialog and either allow or deny.

Comment: Problem we face is we show a spinner as soon as getCurrentPosition is called, but we cant hide it, when not now is selected, so it spins forever.

Answer (score 21):

This is a real pain, and definately not desirable functionality.

The workaround I am using to save the user waiting for ever is to set a timeout to check if the wait spinner is showing after 3 seconds, and if so, hide it and show a manual zip code input:

```
var latlng;

var waitTime = 3000;
try {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            success(position);
        }, showError);
    } else {
        showError("NOT-SUPPORTED");
    }
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($("#getZip div.loading").css("display") != "none") {
            $("#getZip div.loading").hide();
            $("#errorZip").show();
        }
    }, waitTime);
} catch (evt) {
    alert(evt);
}
```

Comment: Why not use the buildin timeout? (see my answer). I know, this is not very well documented, but can be found searching this stackoverflow.com site

Comment: I can't believe I had to resort to this concept. Certainly the geniuses behind the maps factored in that users might not even see that tiny, useless notification at the top of the browser asking to use their location. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Why not show zip on page load and hide it once the location is available? Then it'd work for no-script users as well.

Answer (score 13):

As alexleonard pointed out, the only reliable, cross-browser solution I've found for this is to have a `setTimeout()` to check the state of your `latLng` object/variables, as the `timeout` option of `getCurrentPosition()` doesn't seem to work reliably. The example below was tested in IE11, Chrome33 and Firefox28.

For a more complete solution that uses a jQuery promise, check out my Gist here: https://gist.github.com/GFoley83/10092929

**Example - Hit F12, paste into the console and run**

```
var latLng,
    geoOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 5000, // Wait 5 seconds
        maximumAge: 300000 //  Valid for 5 minutes
    };

var userLocationFound = function(position){
    latLng = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    window.console.log("User confirmed! Location found: " + latLng.lat + ", " + latLng .lng);
}

var userLocationNotFound = function(){
    latLng = {
        lat: -41.29247, // fallback lat 
        lng: 174.7732  // fallback lng
    };
    window.console.log("Fallback set: ", latLng);
}

window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(userLocationFound, userLocationNotFound, geoOptions);

setTimeout(function () {
    if(!latLng){
        window.console.log("No confirmation from user, using fallback");
        userLocationNotFound();
    }else{
        window.console.log("Location was set");
    }
}, geoOptions.timeout + 1000); // Wait extra second
```

Answer (score 4):

This is as per design and apparently is a non-issue. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533

It is left to the developers using the feature to come up with a browser-specific work around for Firefox.

Of note, based on the comment by the FF developer about actual geolocation usage by end users, apparently the Firefox developers are gathering detailed data about what end users are doing with their products.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is actually also an issue in Chrome.

In Chrome an advisory notice appears "site wants to know your location" - it then offers "Allow" and "Deny" as options. With the UI design, the user is more likely to choose either Allow or Deny, which will then return an answer to the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function. However, the user can also click an "X" on the far right of the advisory notice. This is essentially the same as clicking "Not now" in Firefox.

No result is returned to the function.

Looks like a timer has to be implemented to allow for this possible outcome.

Comment: in chrome 34, dismissing the bar with an x is now treated like a deny, which is certainly what i think most people would expect it to do-

Answer (score 3):

Use a promise.  I'm using angularjs that has it's own version of $q to solve the same issue we are all having.

```
            $scope.ByUserPosition = function () {
                //http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                deferred.promise.then(findByPosition, function (data) {
                    console.log('error', data);
                });

                var resolveBy = 1000 * 30;
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    deferred.resolve({ latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude });
                }, function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                }, {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: resolveBy,
                    maximumAge: 0
                });

                $timeout(function() {
                    deferred.reject('timed out');
                }, resolveBy)
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit (after a downvote) 6-11-2013**

As remarked below this answer, this does not solve the problem when a user denies access to location. To the downvote is correct. I keep the answer here, because the timeout is soemthing one should use anyway, and I do not see it in any answer.

The function navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() has the option to send the timeout with it:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     function (position){
        //do someting with position
     },
     function (error){
        // do something with the error (like the code)
     }, 
     {timeout:10000}
);
```

and some other options, like the age of the cached position (maximumAge).
the timeout and maximumage are in milliseconds, so 10000 = 10 secs.

By the way, the default timeout is infinite... so if you do not set the timeout, it will never call the callback for errors....

so in the option like Jamie answered, I would say:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            success(position);
        }, showError, {timeout:3000});
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox if the user selects "Not Now" when asked about location.  It never calls back, even with a timeout.

Comment: Does not fix the problem which is about FireFox not calling callback when user answers "not now". Callbacks are never called.

Comment: Ok, I agree, this does not solve that issue, but at least improve it a bit. In none of the answers I see the timeout option being used at all. I know it helps for other cases, and I had to look long to find anything about the timeout. So in case you agree, I let this answer standing here (as long as there are no downvotes anymore)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to this problem is as follows:

1. When the user clicks the button to get his location automatically, show the spinner and a link beside it "ex: Cancel".
2. If he enables sharing location, then no problem. If he decides to dismiss Firefox popup, the spinner would still be shown but he can click "Cancel" link to stop the spinner an an indicator for dismissing the popup

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to my problem using vanilla es6 `Promises`. Inspired by @LeblancMeneses response.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        resolve(position)
      },
      (error) => {
        resolve(error)
      }
    )
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({})
    }, 8000)
  })
  promise.then((result) => {
      // do something with result
  })
} else {
  console.log('no geolocation available')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var latlng; 
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
         latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    });
}
if(!latlng) {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.718, 11.974); 
}
```

Handeld all my errors :)

Comment: This will always set latLng to (57.718, 11.974), and then possibly override it when/if the user makes a selection. The getCurrentPosition() call is non blocking.

Comment: @SolidALb This is wrong mate. `getCurrentPosition()` is async so all you're doing here is setting `latlng` to `57.718, 11.974` which may or may not get overridden later by the success/failure/timeout callbacks for `getCurrentPosition()`.

Comment: Ok that may be the case. But it has worked for me on every browser for ever(since 2012 ;)). Thanks for pointing it out anyway @GFoley83

Answer (score -1):

watchPosition and getCurrentPosition both accept a second callback which is invoked when there is an error. The error callback provides an argument for an error object. For permission denied, error.code would be error.PERMISSION_DENIED (numeric value 1).

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation

Example:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  console.log("i'm tracking you!");
},
function (error) { 
  if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
     console.log("you denied me :-(");
```

});