# Error handling not working with HTML5 geolocation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple map that should load centered around the user's location as long as they allow HTML5 geolocation. There's a function in place incase they don't choose to allow us to see their location, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("msg");
    function getLocation() {
        if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
        }
        else { x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), mapOptions);
        var acOptions = {
            types: ['establishment']
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), acOptions);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            infoWindow.close();
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br />');
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    }

    function showError(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                break;
            default:
                x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                break;
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getLocation);
```

And of course a `<p>` element is in the body with an id of msg.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function fail never called if user declines to share geolocation in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947637/function-fail-never-called-if-user-declines-to-share-geolocation-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e probably noticing it doesn't fire in FF, because they see the "not now" as not something that *should* fire an error - see here (last response says "stop reopening this bug, it's by design that we do it that way"):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635175

BUT

Timeout is an acceptable property of the options argument (optional third argument) of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. So `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, {timeout:8000});` is the way to get to `showError` after 8 seconds of "inactivity" - which in the case of firefox means "not answering explicitly yes or never".

PS - asked and answered : [function fail never called if user declines to share geolocation in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947637/function-fail-never-called-if-user-declines-to-share-geolocation-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I'm having this issue in Chrome.

Comment: And in Chrome there are only two option: Allow or Deny.

Comment: Strange, it works for me in Chrome (Mac - mountain lion, Chrome 28.0.1500.95, also this morning's Canary). What's the specs on your system/browser?

Comment: Huh, that is strange. I'm running Chrome version 28.0.1500.95 m (not sure if that's the same as yours or if the "m" means something) on Win 8 Pro.