# Native geolocation in web browsers to find the user's current position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cross-browser

I used following code to get user current location. This was work fine in localhost chrome and safari but I face issue with firefox. If I allow to share my location in firefox latest browser it work nicely. But I not allow, it not work. Can anyone please explain me what is the reason for that.

```
function getLocation() {
    // Check for geolocation support
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // Get current position
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            // Success!
            initialize(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
        },
        function () {
            // Gelocation fallback: Defaults
            initialize(new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941));
        });
    }
    else {
        // No geolocation fallback: Defaults
        initialize(new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This bug has been filed to Mozilla few years ago** (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533)

Once the script invokes `getCurrentPosition()`, Firefox prompts the user to share his/her geolocation. At this point, if the user rejects the request, *Firefox unfortunately does not acknowledge the callback function with rejection response*. Therefore, your fallback condition will never fire.

However, there doesn't appear to be any solution provided for this known bug just yet.

Some people have been aware of this issue, see ([function fail never called if user declines to share geolocation in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947637/function-fail-never-called-if-user-declines-to-share-geolocation-in-firefox)). One of viable workarounds for this issue would be using timeout (see details in the link).