# Google maps current location plotting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have below code to find user current location.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // Get current position
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          alert(myLatLng);
        },
        function () {
          alert('fallback');
        });
     }
```

Above code works fine but it prompts the user asking '**would you like to share your location with www.something.com?**'. Now if user does not want to share his location then I need to show some alert. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine you can see here.

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/4cbuhhj2/">This jsfiddle</a>
```

Comment: It works when you select share location option. If i select 'Not Now' option, I need to get different alert.

Comment: In which browser you are trying. I am trying in chrome and its asking me for "Js fiddle want to know your location" and option is allow and block only.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947637/function-fail-never-called-if-user-declines-to-share-geolocation-in-firefox