# Adding additional Callback functions to getCurrentPosition()

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I need to add a callback function when the users allows or denies the `geolocation` request.

Here in my case, already a different team has implemented `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in the same page. But i want to add one more getCurrentPosition() with different callback methods.

Can i use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` again for the same page or do we have any other method to attach additional callbacks.

Comment: I think we can call only one callback method at a time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if geolocation has been DECLINED with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript)

Comment: @Andy. It says for an Error Callback. What would be the case for Success Callback. This will be set only once and will not be continuously watching for the user navigating from one place to another.

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you want to amend the existing code, or add a completely new geolocation request into the page.

Comment: @Andy I would like to add one more geolocation request with new set of callback function for success/error in the same page

Answer (score 1):

As the first commenter said, you can only have one callback, but how about grouping functions within that callback:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundSuccess, foundError);

function foundSuccess() {
  runFunctionOne();
  runFunctionTwo();
}

function foundError() {
  if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    console.log("you denied me :-(");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep..I thought of the same..How about to latch our functionality on the callback function foundSuccess(). When foundSuccess() runs then our functionality also should execute.