# Check if user device's GPS is on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, gps

I am developing an app using jQuery Mobile with PHP. I am not using Phonegap or other frameworks. I need to find user's `geolocation`. If user device's GPS is off, then I cant get a location. now I need to find user device's GPS is on or off.

this is what i using now.

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var lat=position.coords.latitude;
  var long=position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled           also googling it directly i got this one https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148315/check-to-see-if-gps-is-enabled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript

Comment: thank you @bhargav. i think the question and answers belongs to JAVA. PHP is not perfect for this. so i want a javascript.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to check if the device has a GPS module or if it has it enabled through the browser's API. Your laptop will, for example, try to estimate the position based on the IP address with very poor accuracy.

You can, however, use a trick that will likely be good enough for many applications: instead of using the `getCurrentPosition()`, use the `watchPosition()` function with an `options` object `{ enableHighAccuracy: true }` and set a threshold of accuracy that the measurement has to reach for you to accept it as most likely a result based on the GPS module.

What happens when you start to listen to the `watchPosition()` with `enableHighAccuracy` set to true is that if GPS module is available, the API will let it know that you're trying to get a measurement and after up to a few seconds the accuracy distance will go from very high (often thousands of meters - based on IP address, cell tower triangulation, etc.) to a very low (few meters - based on the GPS) and that means that the GPS kicked in. If the accuracy stays at hundreds or thousands of meters, it probably means that there is no GPS module available.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates) for the `GeolocationCoordinates` object (the result within the callback passed to the `watchPosition()`) which comes with the `accuracy` field. I wrote a [longer post](https://dev.to/m3h0w/how-to-get-an-accurate-position-estimate-from-the-geolocation-api-in-javascript-1njf) that also contains a code snippet showing how I use the API within React.

Answer (score 4):

You can call this function on load

```
      // Function to get location
      function getLocation(){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
              var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
              var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
              if (lat == null) {
                  alert("GPS not activated!");
              } else {
                  alert("Latitude: "+ lat + " , Longitude: " + lng );
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Even is the GPS is turned off the geolocation api will return a general location based on the location from the mobile towers and possibly from the ip address.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this one. I am using:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {maximumAge: 60000});
```

In the successCallback i written the codes for what it should do once I got the positions and in the error callback i wrote a simple alert message to prompt the user to turn the GPS on.

Answer (score 0):

**I Implemented This In Real World Project**

> KMaps-API GPS.js

```js
<script>


function getLocationw() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPositionw);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Something Is Wrong";
  }
}

function showPositionw(position) {
    
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  if(lat != null){
    document.write('<center><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"> Please Turn On Your GPS </div></center>')
  }  
 
}

getLocationw();

</script>
```