# To check if the device's GPS is turned on or not

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tizen-web-app

I am developing an app in tizen which displays the nearby gas stations in a given radius.I want to check if the tizen mobile device has it's location turned on or not.If not,tell the user to turn the location on.How can I achieve this?Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if user device's GPS is on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125922/check-if-user-devices-gps-is-on)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind,A simple if-else loop sufficed.Added an alert on the error method  for not recieving the co ordinates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125922/check-if-user-devices-gps-is-on/33582805#33582805

Comment: I've answered the process here.

Comment: Okay,will do.Sorry kind of new here.

Comment: And they are not allowing me to delete

Comment: retry now, this was because your answer had an upvote

Comment: Hmm that's odd... at least we can close it as a duplicate, and I hope that your solution gets upvoted there

Comment: No prob.I anwered because I knew the answer .