# javascript issue with navigator.getCurrentPosition when device location is disabled - no callback

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, location

I am trying to get the user location via

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.check_location.bind(this), this.on_get_position_error.bind(this), { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000 });
```

it works perfectly most of the time. But if the geolocation is disabled in the device settings *(for example on iPhone : Settings App > Privacy > Location services > OFF)*, Safari or Chrome won't call any callback (neither `this.check_location()` nor `this.on_get_position_error()`).

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Yuo might be interested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i fixed it. I don't understand why but adding a 0-delay timeout makes it work :

```
setTimeout(function() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.check_location.bind(this), this.on_get_position_error.bind(this), { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000 });

}.bind(this), 0);
```