# Geolocation marker not appearing, Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I'm building a mobile map using the Google Map API V3. The is a little different than a standard map in that I have categories of markers than you can turn on/off. Everything works great, but I can't seem to get geolocation working. I've tried every combination and code snippet I can find and at most I can get it to register the location request, but it will not display a marker there no matter what I do. I'm sure I'm doing something very simple wrong, but I'm very new to Javascript so the answer is evading me.

Here is a shortened version of my current code (contains an example of everything, but cuts out a lot of the repetitive variables). This example doesn't include the geolocation functions since I've tried so many in different ways I'm not sure which one I would even put on here. The toggleMarkers() function is what I'm using to turn on/off the markers and I'm guessing that's where the problem is for the geolocation marker being displayed. If you could show me how to implement geolocation within this code I would greatly appreciate it!

```
var markers = [];
function initialize() {

//Setting Map
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.73158,-122.636277),
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(0);

//Marker Categories
    var markerBuildings = {
        category: 'buildings',
    }

    var markerParking = {
        category: 'parking',
    }

// Icons
    var iconBuilding = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/building.png',
        new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(16,32));

    var iconAmphitheater = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/amphitheater.png',
        new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(16,32));

//Coordinates

//Buildings
    var vmcb = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.730513,-122.638106),
        map: map,
        url: 'http://www.google.com/',
        icon: iconBuilding,
        data: markerBuildings
    });
    markers.push(vmcb);     
    var vadm = new google.maps.Marker({                        
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.730899,-122.637742),
        map: map,
        url: 'http://www.google.com/',
        icon: iconBuilding,
        data: markerBuildings
    });
    markers.push(vadm);
}

function toggleMarkers(attr,val) {
    if (markers){
        for (i in markers) {
            if(markers[i].data[attr] == val){
                var visibility = (markers[i].getVisible() == true) ? false : true;
                markers[i].setVisible(visibility);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by geolocation in the context of this code. Do you perhaps mean geocoding: e.g., taking a street address and turning it into a (lat,lng)?

Comment: Where is your geolocation code.It seems that the code which you have pasted is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> > If you could show me how to implement geolocation within this code I would greatly appreciate it!

call getGeoLocation() (below) after you create the map object

```
    function getGeoLocation() {
          // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt
    var options = null;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        if (!browserChrome) {
            // By using the 'maximumAge' option, the position
            // object is guaranteed to be at most 15 seconds old.
            // FF and Safari seem to like these options; Chrome does not
            options={enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 15000, timeout: 30000};
          }
        else {
            // Request a position. We only accept cached positions, no matter what 
            // their age is. If the user agent does not have a cached position at
            // all, it will immediately invoke the error callback.
            // http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
            // Chrome will not allow this submitted via the file:// protocol
            options={maximumAge:Infinity, timeout:0};
          }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            centerIsSet = true
            canGeolocate = true;

            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            map.setCenter(pos);

          },
             getGeoLocationErrorCallback(true),

            options);
    }
    else {

      // browser doesn't support geolocation
      getGeoLocationErrorCallback(false);
    }

    }
```