# Geolocation timeout

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm developing a website which will use the geolocation. The fact is I would like to set a timeout if the geolocation system doesn't answer...
I'm using javascript to get the position.

And after check if there is or not a geolocation system,

I used this javascript function :

```
geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallbak, {timeout: 5000});
```

I set the timeout to 5sec. But It doesn't work at all ... I never get a timeout error..

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Thanks

Comment: what does your errorCallback look like?

Comment: I set a switch case with all the possible error.. But I add a console.log and my code is still waiting the geolocation response ...
it never goes to the error callback ...

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: So I added a timeout and it works! :) but the fact is, I get two responses, one from the timeout I just set and the response from  getCurrentPosition that after a certain amount of time give me the answer ... Is there a way to stop the getCurrentPosition call.