# Passing geolocation coordinates to hidden fields in a post form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl

I need to pass some form fields to a Perl file and I have a little form that does the trick.

Now I'd like to add 2 fields for lattitude and longitude using geolocation, but I'm getting blanks for them. I've read it's because geolocation is asynchronous but I can't find how to solve it. I even incorporated some tips from other answers but I can't get it right.

Can anybody help me fix it?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lati =0;
        var longi =0;
        function getPosition(position) 
        {
            lati = position.coords.latitude;
            longi = position.coords.longitude;
            form.latitude.value = lati;
            form.longitude.value = longi;
        }

        function writeLati(form)
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation) { 
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);

            } else {
                form.latitude.value = "3";
                form.longitude.value = "5";
                document.write("Your browser can't do geolocation.");
            }

        }



    </script>
</head>

<body BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" onLoad="writeLati(locform)">


<H1>Page Title</H1>     

<FORM name="locform" ACTION=../cgi-bin/rally.pl METHOD=POST>    

Car Number:         

    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Number" LENGTH=2 />    
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Stage" VALUE=0 />
    <input type="HIDDEN" name="latitude" />
    <input type="HIDDEN" name="longitude"/>
    <P>         
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Send">    
</FORM>     



</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the problem is just some javascript errors.

Starting with `<body BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" onLoad="writeLati(locform)">`

`locform` doesn't exist. You need to use something like `document.getElementById` to get what you are expecting here. (To use getElementById you need to put an ID on your form obviously).

Also in `function getPosition(position)`

You are trying to assign `form.latitude.value`, however `form` is a local variable in the `function writeLati` it cannot be accessed here.

It worked for me after fixing those problems.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but Im not a programmer (well I used to be 30 years ago when languages and logic were totally defferent). Would you please correct my code with your suggestions and post it?