# delay further processing until "if statement" executed, in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, callback

I have an "if statement" like so:

```
if (webservice returns true) {

                    alert("booyah");
               }

alert("hooray");
```

Trouble is that the webservice is very slow. And "hooray" gets triggered before "booyah" even when the webservice returns true.

How can I pause all further processing until this "if statement" is properly evaluated?

I'm thinking that some kind of callback function might be needed here. How will I structure it?

Additionally, is there some way to have a wait animation on the webpage while this "if statement" is being waited on?

Comment: Generally yes a callback is the thing to do, but it depends how you are calling `webservice`. Are you doing a standard ajax call? Are you using jquery? It would be best to post the code to call the webservice

Comment: @Rhumborl Not using jQuery. The service is navigator.geolocation , which allows a webbrowser to identify a user's location. The specific if condition is:  if(navigator.geolocation) { }

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt) and its answers. In general, it's better to be more specific when describing your problem. )

Comment: @raina77ow You offered a useful link. However, that problem is about reducing the (otherwise infinite) timeout of the navigator service, whereas I want to stop all further processing until I get a yes or no reply from the service.

Comment: @user1883050: What the example in the question shows, is *also* a callback. In other words, a function which only gets called *after* the webservice call returns. That's what you are looking for, correct?