# Javascript: running on mobile but not on desktop(chrome, opera, safari)

Tags: javascript

I'm working with the **HTML5 geolocation api**. I'm getting a weird **error**. i got a function called `doGeolocate` that is called when the user land on the page. That load the map with the wright location data. And i got a button that recall the same function when ever the user want to recenter the map. But when a user tap the button on a desktop(chrome,opera, safari) except firefox it doesn't work.
While on the other there is no problem. Once debug it seem like the code locationCallback isn't call properly the second time even tho it is on load.

```
doGeolocate: function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("doGeolocate");
        var locationCallback = helper.callback(this, function(position) {
            this.initialGeolocationPosition(position);
            if(!this.positionMarker){
            this.createPositionMarker(position);
            }
        });  
        var err = function(err) {
            console.log("");
        };
        var options = {
            maximumAge: 0
        };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationCallback,err,options);
    }
  },
```

Comment: perhaps same as this old problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: Did desktop browser ask you to allow geolocation?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/591758/how-do-i-make-chrome-forget-a-no-to-geolocation-on-a-site

Comment: @Skarlinski Yes it did and that's why  it always work the first time. That's not the issue but thanks!

Comment: what is helper.callback() for? It looks like the weakest link

Comment: it allow me to get access to function and attribute that are not in the scope of the current one.