# Maps, Ripple emulator work, android emulator NO

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying a code gogole maps with cordoba with 2 different emulators , ripple chroome and the Android emulator normal .
Ripple works and shows me a map geographic location , while the emulator Android rest a whole screen gray .
Why ?

Comment: I think I had this before. And the solution is to wait... my Map shown up after something like 3 minutes.

Comment: Nope, simple map load in a few moment, while geolocation not load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the emulator is just failed to report its location.

And later I realized what is making that gray screen is we did not handle  `time-out` probably. When we are getting the user location, it might take forever before the browser returns the location. Best practice is to first set a location and then update the maps later when the location becomes available. Also we should set the timeout for the geolocation too, [as it is default to be Infinity.](http://shapeshed.com/html5-geolocation-api/)

I created a jsfiddle for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/x1115zw3/1/

=-=-=-=

To put the map in HYBRID, you should add `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` in the maps option. So you mapOptions should looks like:

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
```

Comment: before your ` // Try HTML5 geolocation`, try to set a default location. Look at line 19 of the jsfiddle. Also refer to this post for more information on timeout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: I understood , but as I enter a default location without sending in error all ?

Comment: yea, that would prevent user stuck in the gray screen, and your map would be functional even if the HTML5 geolocation does not return a location, or occur errors

Comment: Thank you, could you come Even Change the map type in " hybrid " ? Why when I try to put it in the map options me everything goes wrong .

Comment: To put the map in HYBRID, you should add `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` in the maps option

Comment: I had already tried in this way , when I put it sends me everything in error and no longer see the map , the same thing when I try to change the marker icon

Comment: if you try jsfiddle I see my mistake with map id

Comment: now the map worked, but geolocation in the emulator not see