# Geolocation api not giving accurate user location

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

i am designing a web application in which a user can find services related to his city address (e.g all educational institute in his city ).For this i am trying to add auto search user location in system. I am using Geolocation api for getting user location. **Now problem is "Geolocation api is not providing me accurate user address".I live in Sahiwal and it shows my location in Lahore.** Kindly help me i have to submit my project next Monday....:( First time asking a question so sorry for English and wrong explanation of my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition sometimes works sometimes doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different browser but most likely it is because your computer does not know its location.  Most of the time mobile devices will give you the correct location so try it on a mobile device.