# getCurrentPosition only fires once in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, geolocation

Take a look at this code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(){
    console.log("a");
});
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(){
    console.log("b");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/sxb3j2bv/

After the permission is granted by the user, I would expect the console to have logged

```
> "a"
> "b"
```

and indeed this is what happened in Chrome. However on Firefox, for some reason it only fires once and only logs `"b"`:

```
> "b"
```

What can I do about it? Is that a bug?

Comment: In chrome, you must have got `"b"` and then `"a"`

Comment: My assumption is second `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is invoked too and it overrides initial permission prompt. As you allow second prompt, you get `"b"` in the console. As per the docs, _Be aware that each browser has its own policies and methods for requesting this permission._ [[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation)]

Comment: @RayonDabre You are right. `"b"` comes before `"a"`.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reusing the previous request's promise:

```
// Note that this is using AngularJS
.service("demo_geolocation_service", function($q){
    var ongoingRequest = false; // This is to deal with strange Firefox behavior
                                //  where .getCurrentPosition only fires callback once
                                //  even when called multiple times

    return function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if(!ongoingRequest){
            // store promise
            ongoingRequest = deferred.promise;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                deferred.resolve({latitude: pos.coords.latitude, longitude: pos.coords.longitude});
                ongoingRequest = undefined;
            }, function(){
                deferred.reject();
                ongoingRequest = undefined;
            });
        }else{
            // reuse previous promise
            ongoingRequest.then(function(latlng){
                deferred.resolve(latlng);
            }, function(){
                deferred.reject();
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because the second call executes before the user has accepted the location permission for the first.

However, you probably want to look at

> navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

rather than making multiple requests to get the position.

Comment: I'm not trying to make multiple calls to constantly "update" my internal data. The reason why my code makes multiple `getCurrentPosition` calls is because there are different modules in the page that requires geolocation, resulting in multiple calls to `getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: If you don't need an updated location, then just call getCurrentPosition once and then store the returned value, and use the value elsewhere.