# JS Get user location not working

Tags: javascript

Anyone can please help me Why below given code is not working and How can I resolve it? And sorry my grammatical or spelling mistake.

JS:

```
<script>

    function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position){
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you calling the functions?

Comment: of course man I am calling it on document ready

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: If you're not on localhost, you need HTTPS (in Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            showPosition(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position){
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
    }

</script>
```

You never called showPosition, If I´m right you want to call showPosition with the value of getCurrentPosition.

Comment: can you please check on my url http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing where I am wrong?

Comment: look at the console, getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See url for more details. Its not based on your code by it self, it just get blocked cause you dont use secure https

Answer (score 1):

you should create a div for position and you can add the position innerHtml of the div.
just like that;

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you please check on my url http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing where I am wrong?

Comment: @ShahRushabh your URL doesn't have HTTPS. Are you using Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

you don't call getLocation() function you should trigger the get Location() with event for example on click