# navigator.geolocation returns error from second execution on - IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, geolocation

When executing `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);` for the first time, I'm able to get the user's location. however from the second execution on, the function returns the error:

> The current position could not be determined.

I have followed the advice given in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt) with no success, how can i get this to work?

Here you can find a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2rnr7tw/3/) to quickly see the error.

```
//Pass this options to the getCurrentPosition
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};
//function to execute if the current position was succesfully retrieved
function success(pos) {
console.log(pos);
  var crd = {lat: pos.coords.latitude, lng : pos.coords.longitude };
    var myPre = document.querySelector('pre');
  myPre.textContent = JSON.stringify(crd);
  myPre.style.color = someColor(); // use a diferent color just to see it's a new execution of the code
};
//execute this on error
function error(err) {
  var myPre = document.querySelector('pre');
  myPre.textContent = err;
  myPre.style.color = someColor(); // use a diferent color
};
//attach function to button
var myButton = document.querySelector('button');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
});
```

Comment: Rolled back edition because I intentionally did not add a code snippet, it doesn't reflect the error and therefore is not useful. Thus the fiddle, where the error can be seen and tested.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is the following:

The IE user only allows the website (script) (by default settings) to run `getCurrentLocation` once. The user has to grant an exception for it to run multiple times.

> However I don't know (and can't really find any documentation) if this behaviour is by design or a bug. The solution below is a work-around.

Use [`watchposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593068(v=vs.85).aspx) instead after the initial succes circumnavigates this *bug*. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b2rnr7tw/6/

In this fiddle I set up a `watchPosition` and as soon as it updates it shows the new location. After that it is cancelled (else it keeps updating).

```
//Pass this options to the getCurrentPosition
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

var watch = null;
var watchId = null;
//function to execute if the current position was succesfully retrieved
function success(pos) {

  var crd = {lat: pos.coords.latitude, lng : pos.coords.longitude };
  var myPre = document.querySelector('pre');
  myPre.textContent = JSON.stringify(crd);
  myPre.style.color = someColor(); // use a diferent color
  watch.clearWatch(watchId); //after success clear the watchId.
};
//execute this on error
function error(err) {
  var myPre = document.querySelector('pre');
  myPre.textContent = err;
  myPre.style.color = someColor(); // use a diferent color
  //keep running the watchPosition if on error, however you can use a counter to only try it a few times (recommended)
};
//attach function to button
var myButton = document.querySelector('button');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (!watch)
  {
    watch = navigator.geolocation;
    watch.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
   }
   else
   {
   watchId = watch.watchPosition(success, error, options);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any documentation either, your method works but there is a strange behaviour, from the second execution, when we start executing watchPosition instead of getCurrentPosition, it executes the error function and then the success function, so visually you can see it threw an error and shortly after the text is updated with the Lat and Lng values, just tried with a couple different computer, do you get this as well? I saw the function's docs but the order of the parameters sent is fine

Comment: I got the visual behaviour as well, but that can be easily corrected with some extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Mouser's solution worked for me in IE11 however breaks Edge, so we need browser detection. Here is my solution tested in IE11, Edge 14, FFx and Chrome (latest versions of FFx and Chrome at time of writing)

```
            var currentPositionHasBeenDisplayed = false;

            if (navigator.geolocation) {

                var options = {};

                var isIE = document.documentMode; //IE 8+

                // IE only allows one call per script to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, so we need a workaround
                if (currentPositionHasBeenDisplayed == true && isIE) {
                    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                         function (pos) {
                             var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(pos.coords.latitude), parseFloat(pos.coords.longitude));
                             map.setCenter(myLatLng);
                         },
                         function (error) {  },
                         options);
                }
                else {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function (pos) {
                            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(pos.coords.latitude), parseFloat(pos.coords.longitude));
                            map.setCenter(myLatLng);
                            currentPositionHasBeenDisplayed = true;
                        }, 
                        function (error) { return false; },
                        options);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have implemented the same but it breaks the IE11, also I tried clearing the watch position after watch success.. :(