# TypeError: undefined is not an object( evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, navigator, react-native-maps

I have recently started working on react-native, now am trying to access react-native-maps for the reason wherever I click on the map it should give me the coordinates. I installed react-native-map and tried to use below method

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
```

I am getting below error.

> ```
> E | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')
>                              │ 
>                              │ This error is located at:
>                              │ in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
>                              │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
>                              │ in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>                              │ in RCTView (at View.js:35)
>                              │ in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>                              └ in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
> ```

My code looks similar like this.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }

      this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000});
  }
```

Also I tried with some other methods like

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
```

and

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
```

How can I solve this problem and make these methods work from react-native-maps

I am using `import MapView from 'react-native-maps';` this import

Comment: Hi, can you check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: No that is something different. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for, but if you don't have any problem in using this react-native-geolocation library from [react-native-community](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation), you can easily follow its great [example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation/blob/master/example/GeolocationExample.js). Please don't forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml file like this -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You also need to add the meta-data in the manifest file -

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

You can easily generate the API key using Google API console

Comment: These lines are already there in the that, still not working.

Comment: @DeepakN Please try and go through the following [example](https://github.com/yash-vardhan-mishra/BareReactNativeApp/blob/master/screens/MapScreen.js) It was working fine the last time I checked, I've used the crude approach by calling Geolocation.getCurrentPosition inside the constructor, you can use it inside componentDidMount. I hope it helps.

Comment: yeah Geolocation.something...() works but not navigator.geolocation.something..() does not work.Ok i will go through it and let you know soon

Comment: @DeepakN that is why I recommended this library in the second line of this answer, I also faced the same problem while trying to access the location using the navigator.geolocation, let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes, it the Geolocation.somefunction() works fine. Actually I was using React-native-location-view where it users navigation.geolocation thing. I changed the code in that library that works but is there any way of using navigation.geolocation??

Comment: @DeepakN I'll update you if I find anything, I'm glad that you are able to make use of react-native-geolocation.
Meanwhile if you are still in doubt and want to use the same 'react-native-location-view' you can raise an issue on their [github](https://github.com/superapp/react-native-location-view) repository. I haven't used it personally so I don't know how to work it out