# javascript : I keep getting the same location latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, location

My code for getting a location is something like that:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (succes) => {
        if (document.getElementById('hiddenDivLatitude'))
            document.getElementById('hiddenDivLatitude').value = succes.coords.latitude;

        if (document.getElementById('hiddenDivLongitude'))
            document.getElementById('hiddenDivLongitude').value = succes.coords.longitude;
        
        alert('S-au identificat urmatoarele coordonate: \r\nlat: ' + succes.coords.latitude.toFixed(6) + ', long: ' + succes.coords.longitude.toFixed(6));
        document.forms[0].submit();
    },
    (error) => {
        var errorMessage = error.code;

        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                errorMessage = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                errorMessage = "Locatia nu se poate prelua."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                errorMessage = "Timeout. Mai incearca o data."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                errorMessage = "Nu se pot prelua coordonatele."
                break;
        }

        alert(errorMessage);
        x.innerHTML = errorMessage;
    },
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 0,
        timeout: 20000
    }
)
```

I specify that property maximumAge is set to 0 so the device should retrieve the newest location.
The device retrieves location in the following manner:

```
44.433329   26.0369307,
44.433329   26.0369307,
44.433329   26.0369307,
44.433329   26.0369307,
44.4333286  26.0369289,
44.4347303  26.0286253,
44.4347303  26.0286253
```

And I really do not understand why the cache location doesn't reset immediately.
I specify that the browser being used is Chrome and the device OS is Android.

Comment: this can answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt